# Minimum mean over all random variables subject to logarithm constraint

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations

Does the following problem have a solution?
$$
\min_X \mathbb{E} X
\quad\text{subject to}\quad
\mathbb{E} \log X = C.
$$

Here, the minimization is with respect to all integrable random variables $X$ and $C$ is some constant. Alternatively, instead of minimizing over random variables, one may equivalently view this as optimizing over the space of probability measures.

Comment: Put $X=e^Y$. By Jensen's inequality, $E e^Y\ge e^{EY}=e^C$. Since concentrating $X$ at $e^C$ achieves that bound, it is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $X>0$ a.s. (so the constraint can be satisfied) and write $Y=\log X$. 
By Jensen's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), 
$\mathbb{E} X \ge e^{\mathbb{E} Y}=e^C$, so the minimum is attained for $X$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X=e^C)=1$.

Comment: I beat you by 3 minutes, but I hope we didn't just do someone's homework.